# Variable not retaining its value

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

Hi I'm new to swift so bear with me if I'm missing something obvious.

I have a function `bestSum` which accepts 2 parameters `targetNumber` and `numbers`, which is an array. The `bestSum` function returns an array which contains elements from `numbers` which can be added to get the `targetNumber`. The returned array is also the shortest combination of numbers that adds up to form `targetNumber` . If no combination of numbers could add up to `targetNumber` then the function `bestSum` returns nil.

```
    var bestSumMemoryDictionary : [Int : [Int]?] = [:]

    print(bestSum(targetNumber: 4, numbers: [2,4], memoryDictionary: &bestSumMemoryDictionary))



 func bestSum(targetNumber : Int , numbers : [Int] , memoryDictionary : inout [Int : [Int]? ] ) -> [Int]? {
    
    if let value = memoryDictionary[targetNumber]{
        return value
    }
    
    if targetNumber == 0 {
        return []
    }
    
    if targetNumber < 0 {
        return nil
    }
    
    var returningArray : [Int]? = nil
    
    for number in numbers {
        
        let remainder = targetNumber - number
        
        if var bestSumValueArray =  bestSum(targetNumber: remainder, numbers: numbers, memoryDictionary: &memoryDictionary){
            
            bestSumValueArray.append(number)
            
            guard var returningArray = returningArray else {
                returningArray = bestSumValueArray
                continue
            }
       
            if bestSumValueArray.count < returningArray.count{
                returningArray = bestSumValueArray
            }
            print(returningArray)
        }
        print(returningArray)
        
    }
    
    memoryDictionary[targetNumber] = returningArray
    return returningArray
}
```

The returned array is `Optional([2, 2])` to generate the sum of `4` , where as the expected and correct value is `Optional([4])`.

Issue is happening in the line that contains `returningArray = bestSumValueArray` . The print statement below that line is printing `[4]` , Where as the next print statement print `Optional([2, 2])` . Why the value of `returningArray`  is different in 2 consecutive print statements ? What am i missing here. Would appreciate any help.

[image: Debugger ScreenShot]

Comment: Have you experimented with the debugger? Set a breakpoint and step through the code and you can see what is happening.

Comment: Yes i experimented it with both playground and debugger. In debugger i tried with `didset` and `willset` for `returningArray ` and it never gets called while `returningArray = bestSumValueArray` . Not able to come to a solid conclusion

Comment: What does the debugger have to do with didSet and willSet? Using the debugger, set a breakpoint at the top of your loop and step through the code. You can see the value of each variable at the print statements and see each step that mutates them.

Comment: could you try replacing the `guard` with  `if returningArray == nil {  returningArray = bestSumValueArray }`

Comment: @jnpdx I did step by step follow of the code and somehow magically `returningArray 
` value changes between consecutive `print` statements even though there is no line between them . I put `didset` just to see if there is something that is messing up my `returningArray ` .

Comment: @workingdog used ur code and nothing changed still same issue exists.

Comment: hint this `guard var returningArray` creates a different variable called `returningArray` to the `returningArray` that is declared outside the `for` loop.  Try changing it to `guard var notReturningArray = returningArray` and you will see what I mean

Comment: Seems like with your two `returningArray`s you think you're working with a reference to one array. Swift's `Array` is a value type.

Comment: Thank you guys for ur help . I really appreciate all ur time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you define 2 variables with same name :

```
var returningArray : [Int]? = nil // 1st definition

for number in numbers {
    
    let remainder = targetNumber - number
    
    if var bestSumValueArray =  bestSum(targetNumber: remainder, numbers: numbers, memoryDictionary: &memoryDictionary){
        
        bestSumValueArray.append(number)
        
        guard var returningArray = returningArray else {
            returningArray = bestSumValueArray
            continue
        } // 2nd definition
   
        if bestSumValueArray.count < returningArray.count{
            returningArray = bestSumValueArray
        }
        print(returningArray) // 2nd variable
    }
    print(returningArray) // 1st variable
    
}
```